# Swizzling NSBundle for reskinnable demo

Tags: ios7, nsbundle, objective-c-runtime, swizzling, asset-catalog

I'm trying to build an application (not for app store distribution) that can be reskinned by downloading a bundle containing images and strings files.

For localization, I've had no problems swizzling `localizedStringForKey:value:table:` to load my custom strings, however for images I have much more trouble.

My project is using storyboards without asset catalogs and targets iOS 7. I've tried swizzling the following methods on NSBundle to capture image loading from a storyboard, but none of them are hit (at least for png files):

```
URLForResource:withExtension:
URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:localization:
URLsForResourcesWithExtension:subdirectory:
```

I do see attempts to load `.car` files (this is the asset catalog format) however these return a `nil` URL. I've also attempted to swizzle the `pathForResource:` versions of the above methods, but no new calls are captured.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try pathForResource ofType? Just a shot in the dark, but maybe try these too:  bundleURL , resourceURL, executableURL.

Comment: Yep, it is called by the URLForResource function... or the other way around, I don't remember anymore.

Comment: But you could rebuild the URL based on the stuff you download and stuff into the documents directory right?

Comment: Yes, but that would only work if `URLForResource` or `pathForResource` was actually called... that's my problem. I think I'll have to try using Asset Catalogs and see if I can get any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to intercept requests for individual image files in `NSBundle` and switched over to the asset catalog system. The `URLForResource` methods in `NSBundle` are called and always look for Assets.car, simply returning Assets.car from my own bundle caused my custom images to be loaded. This works for `[UIImage imagedNamed:]` as well as loading from nibs.

For completeness sake, to generate an asset catalog you need to use `actool` located in XCode.app. I used `actool` for the simulator and copied the command from the build log (this catalog also worked on my iPhone 5S...):

```
actool --platform iphonesimulator --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --target-device iphone --compress-pngs --compile  [path_to_output_bundle] [path_to_xcassets]
```

Both of the paths have to been absolute paths otherwise `actool` fails.